# Is there a quick way to send a copy of a mosaico email to one person?

Tags: civimail, mosaico

So this is the scenario:

We sent a moasico email to our list, it was an invitation to an event we are hosting.

Someone gives me a name of one more person and says, can you send the invite to them too?

Currently I have to do the following:

- Create a group and put them in it.
- copy the the email.
- Change recipients to the new group
- Send email
- Eventually delete group

It would save a bit of time if I could just put a contact email in the recipients field, like I can when I do Contact -> New Email. Is that possible?